# Publishing Pages / WCM - Good resources for implementation?

Tags: 2010, publishing-site, publishing, intranet, wcm

Are there any good resources available for implementing web content management using publishing pages in SharePoint 2010? I know the bits and pieces, but am looking for example implementations.

I'm trying to look for the best ways to make the most of SharePoint in an Intranet scenario where there are both pages and documents, and at the same time make it user friendly for the content owners to manage.

I have resources on branding, WCM/ECM as a larger topic, etc., but I'm missing examples on implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a 3 part series that discusses about Publishing features and concepts surrounding it
http://sharepointchick.com/archive/2011/01/12/sharepoint-enterprise-features-functionality.aspx

Another article that discusses sharepoint publshing feature
http://www.thesharepointmuse.com/2011/12/lesson-learned-when-you-need-to-use-publishing-in-sharepoint/

Finally, I would still suggest read this book 
**[Professional SharePoint Branding](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470584645) - by Randy Drisgill.**

It has all the information you need concerning the SharPoint publshing infrastructure.

Concerning Information Architecture for your intranet go through this following links
http://www.harbar.net/presentations/suguk_ia.pdf
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joelo/archive/2007/03/16/information-architecture-and-the-information-architect.aspx
http://www.cmswire.com/cms/information-management/5-critical-steps-to-sharepoint-information-architecture-planning-014188.php

This is a Microsoft case study of MOSS 2007 information architecture in depth
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=91053

Besides, the above links I recommend the following quick points before you proceed

**Define what before how.**
Do a great deal assessment on what kind of organization, the size of the employees , departments and divisions , current processes , modes of offline employee collaboration and create a solution roadmap on sharepoint and how to leverage the best using an intranet build on top it. This "what" should be as descriptive and clarity must reside before you proceed on "How" to implement them.

**Use only whats needed.**
SharePoint comes with multitude of collaboration features like document sharing, blogs ,wikis, bi ,team dsicussions, search , social sites etc. A majority of intranet implementation on sharepoint somewhat drifts towards this feature creep and adds unneccessary site templates and enable features which are either not used or have no real requirement for the business. Keep things simple and ensure only minimum required features are present per site.

**Document everything.**
The title says it all. Document every corner of the farm including services, servers , roles , web applications and site collections , site collection administrators , features activated per site , hierarchy of subsites ,etc. This document will become an indispensible resource once your intranet grows.

Comment: Another resource I found helpful:

SharePoint 2010 for Internet Sites Implementers' Course
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/hh126807

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to start with on [how to create a Publishing page layouts](https://web.archive.org/web/20140808132926/http://blog.beckybertram.com:80/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=71) and [Content Types](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2011/11/23/sharepoint-2010-cookbook-how-to-create-custom-page-layout-for-publishing-site-using-visual-studio-2010.aspx%27). Try packaging them with [Master page and Branding](https://web.archive.org/web/20150908094201/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bobgerman/archive/2011/01/31/packaging-master-pages-and-page-layouts-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx) using Visual Studio and you're good to go.

Comment: Falak, your second link gives "Access Denied"

Answer (score -1):

you can use the SharePoint add-on Innofactor Content Distribution Service. It has been designed to make site publishing from SharePoint 2010 fairly easy without concessions to design or functionality. This site for example was made in 1.5 days with SharePoint 2010 and including the design: www.liitykiltaan.fi

http://cloud.innofactor.com describes the whole solution. It really makes publishing from SharePoint easy. Furthermore, anyone can administrate the websites with this add-on.

Maybe that helps.

Comment: We  require relevant answers and disclosure of any affiliation with  products or websites. Please see [May I promote products or websites I  am affiliated with here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) for guidelines.